# Code style formatting without google-java-format plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, formatting, code-formatting, google-java-format

Please tell me how to use code style formatting in IDEA?

I used the **google-java-format plugin** and it works very well for me.

An example of my code using the **google-java-format plugin**:

```
public Single<MonetaryAmount> calculateInterest(Status status, Account account) {
    var accountId = account.getKey().getRootId();
    return signIn
        .resolve(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5)
        .flatMap(
            loginPeriod ->
                findBalances(
                        lowestPeriodStartDate(loginPeriod, accountId),
                        highestPeriodEndDate(loginPeriod, accountId),
                        status.getStatusDetails().getLoginConfiguration(),
                        accountId)
                    .map(balances -> getInterestAccountBalance(balances, status.getSource()))
                    .flatMap(
                        accountBalance ->
                            moneyCalculator.calculateBalanceMoney(accountBalance, loginPeriod)));
  }
```

I also decided to try **intellij-java-google-style.xml**, which I found on github.

I went to *Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java* and imported this scheme there.

In the end, I ended up like this (not very pretty):

```
public Single<MonetaryAmount> calculateInterest(
        Status status,
        Account account) {
        var accountId = account.getKey().getRootId();
        return signIn.resolve(param1, param2, param3,
            param4, param5)
            .flatMap(loginPeriod -> findBalances(lowestPeriodStartDate(loginPeriod, accountId),
                highestPeriodEndDate(loginPeriod, accountId),
                status.getStatusDetails().getLoginConfiguration(),
                accountId)
                .map(balances -> getInterestAccountBalance(balances,
                    status.getSource()))
                .flatMap(accountBalance -> moneyCalculator
                    .calculateBalanceMoney(
                        accountBalance,
                        loginPeriod))
            );
    }
```

I tried to set my own settings for *tab size, indent, continuation indent* - but it didn't help.

Tell me how, using your settings in IDEE, to achieve the same beautiful formatting as it happens using the ***google-java-format plugin***?

I don't want to use a plugin.

Thank you!

Comment: If you want the formatting given to you by _google-java-format_ then why don't you want to use the plugin?

Comment: We don't want to include third party plugins. I would like to be able to do without plugins if possible